# Best way to scroll Webpage using CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a site where scrolling is required.

Which is the best way to scroll webpage using css or javascript?

Note: It should be work in Mobile Browser also.

Comment: Native scrollbars of a browser, definitely.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your talking about parallax scrolling, the question has been answered above.

for parallax scrolling effect, this is a pretty good example and tutorial to get you started.

http://callmenick.com/post/simple-parallax-scrolling-effect

Answer (score 0):

As soon as your content exceeds the height or width of a `div`, `iframe` or your `body` you are using the browsers scrollbar automatically. This **native implementation** is the most common and convenient way. It does not matter if you are displaying your content on a desktop, tablet or smartphone browser.

You can [style or extend](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-scroll-bar/) the scrollbar using CSS and JS.

Answer (score 0):

Neither CSS or JS is required. All websites let the user see the overflowed content applying a scroll, automatically, for any browser including mobile and tablet browsers, pc/laptop browsers and TV browsers.

There's nothing you need to do in order to allow scrolling on a website.

If you want to customize the scrollbar, CSS is unable to do so. You need JS, and I highly recommend you to use any of the well-known plugins on there, as it is a difficult task when ensuring that it would work perfecly on any device.

Example of plugin: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/